# Vue Bootstrap img not displaying from assets folder

Tags: image, css, vue.js, bootstrap-4

I am trying to display an image like what is done in this tutorial https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/components/image/

Here is my code

```
<template>
 <b-container fluid class="p-4 bg-dark">
 <b-row>
 <b-col>
  <b-img rounded="circle" thumbnail fluid src="require('../assets/sweetcart.jpg')" alt="Thumbnail" />
</b-col>
<b-col>
  <b-img rounded="circle" thumbnail fluid src="https://picsum.photos/250/250/?image=58" alt="Thumbnail" />
</b-col>
<b-col>
  <b-img rounded="circle" thumbnail fluid src="https://picsum.photos/250/250/?image=59" alt="Thumbnail" />
</b-col>
</b-row>
</b-container>
</template>
```

Here is my file structure, although im sure the file path for the image is correct as I have been able to display the image in its own div tag, issue seems to be something to do with bootstrap?

[image: File Structure]

I am working within the Home.vue file.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix this by placing the image in the static folder instead of the assets folder.

I am still curious as to why this wouldn't work in the assets folder?

These guys are discussing something similar but there seemed to be no definitive answer.

https://github.com/vuejs/Discussion/issues/202

Comment: Like the Github issue you listed above, it's very likely to be related to how Webpack loads the folders. If you can find the configs and have a look, it may be able to shed some light on it. (In Vue 3 cli, it's something unlikely).